# Converting a 'for loop' from Javascript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to convert the following javascript code to python.

```
let speed = 50;
const lightCount = 1;
const lights = [[200, 10];

const isRed = (speed, dist, dur) =>
    (18 * dist) % (10 * speed * dur) >= (5 * speed * dur);

for(let i = 0; i < lightCount; i++) {
    if (isRed(speed, lights[i][0], lights[i][1])) {
        speed--; // Reduce speed
        i = -1; // Start again
    }
}
console.log(speed);
```

I tried the following in python, but it is not working:

```
speed = 50
light_count = 1
lights = [[200, 10]

def is_red(speed, dist, dur):
    if (18 * dist) % (10 * speed * dur) >= (5 * speed * dur):
        return True
    return False

for i in range(light_count):
    if is_red(speed, lights[i][0], lights[i][1]):
        speed -= 1
        i = -1

print(speed)
```

The answer is supposed to be 36 but it is showing 49.
It always loops only once.
Please suggest a solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a really simple typo; your Python code has `i -= 1` while in JavaScript it's `i = -1`. Just change the Python code to match the JavaScript code.

Comment: You haven’t translated the last line of the loop correctly - compare them, you’ll see what I mean

Comment: `i = -1` and `i -= 1` are two different things. I don't know why you thought you should change that while translating.

Comment: The Python code has another typo: `[[200, 10]` is missing a closing `]`. However, you can't control Python's `for` loop by assigning to `i` inside the loop like that. It will just get a fresh value from the `range` next time around. You should instead write an enclosing `while` loop that tries decreasing `speed` values until it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing `i` will not step the loop back. `int`s are immutable, so you are just editing the state of a temporary variable. You can try using a `while` loop, and just incrementing back i.

Example:

```
speed = 50
light_count = 1
lights = [[200, 10]

def is_red(speed, dist, dur):
    if (18 * dist) % (10 * speed * dur) >= (5 * speed * dur):
        return True
    return False

i = 0
while i < light_count:
    if is_red(speed, lights[i][0], lights[i][1]):
        speed -= 1
    #    i -= 1
    #i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
del i
```